# Custom admin menu order fails if slugs are complicated

Tags: wp-admin, admin-menu, add-menu-page, menu-order

I'm not able to reorder WP Admin menu items when pages added with `add_menu_page` have complicated slugs. At least I think that's the problem...

First I create the custom menu items, which is working as expected:

```php
function sma_simplify_admin_ui() {
    global $user_ID;
    if ( $user_ID != 1 ) {
        add_menu_page( 'Menu', 'Menu', 'edit_posts', 'nav-menus.php?action=edit&menu=16', '', 'dashicons-menu' );
        add_menu_page( 'Memberships', 'Memberships', 'edit_posts', 'edit.php?post_type=wc_user_membership', '', 'dashicons-groups' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'sma_simplify_admin_ui' );
```

The new items **cannot** be reordered. If I put the exact slugs given when they were created, `menu_order` (and `custom_menu_order`) simply ignore them and my new items are always at the bottom of the menu.

```php
function sma_reorder_admin_ui($menu_ord) {  
    if (!$menu_ord) return true;
    return array(
        'nav-menus.php?action=edit&menu=16',
        'edit.php?post_type=wc_user_membership',
        /* truncated for clarity, there is more stuff */
    );
}  
add_filter( 'custom_menu_order', 'sma_reorder_admin_ui' ); 
add_filter( 'menu_order', 'sma_reorder_admin_ui' );
```

Setting a priority when I create them isn't letting me reorder them either, which is *really* weird...

I'm theorising the slug expected by `custom_menu_order` & `menu_order` isn't what I'm giving it, but *I don't know what to give it*. I've also tried every single slug/key/*thing* that I get when I vardump `$GLOBAL['menu']`.

Please help me work out how to reorder my menu items!

Comment: Inside the `sma_reorder_admin_ui` function if you just dump or log out the original values of `$menu_ord` then you should be able to see what it expects.

Comment: I hadn't thought to vardump `$menu_ord` specifically, but that does make sense as a way to see the current slugs. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the action I create the menu items from `admin_init` to `admin_menu`. The former runs far too early and I suppose was creating conflicts. I am now able to reorder my items by referencing them by their original slugs.

For future reference and in case it is helpful to others, [the WP documentation for `add_menu_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/#notes) specifically recommends hooking to `admin_menu`.